# how to send text input value in jquery with image upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery function which makes request with php file and upload the image on server here is the jquery code, It's Much Big to read.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//customize values to suit your needs.
var max_file_size       = 8048576; //maximum allowed file size
var allowed_file_types  = ['image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg']; //allowed file types
var message_output_el   = 'output'; //ID of an element for response output
var loadin_image_el     = 'loading-img'; //ID of an loading Image element

var bla = $('#contentMessage').val(); // how can i send this variable too in post
//You may edit below this line but not necessarily
var options = { 
    //dataType:  'json', //expected content type
    target: '#' + message_output_el,   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit: before_submit,  // pre-submit callback 
    success: after_success,  // post-submit callback 
    resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
}; 

$('#upload_form').submit(function(){
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); //trigger ajax submit
    return false; //return false to prevent standard browser submit
}); 

function before_submit(formData, jqForm, options){
    var proceed = true;
    var error = []; 
    /* validation ##iterate though each input field
    if you add extra text or email fields just add "required=true" attribute for validation. */
    $(formData).each(function(){ 

        //check any empty required file input
        if(this.type == "file" && this.required == true && !$.trim(this.value)){ //check empty text fields if available
            error.push( this.name + " is empty!");
            proceed = false;
        }

        //check any empty required text input
        if(this.type == "text" && this.required == true && !$.trim(this.value)){ //check empty text fields if available
            error.push( this.name + " is empty!");
            proceed = false;
        }

        //check any invalid email field
        var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        if(this.type == "email" && !email_reg.test($.trim(this.value))){ 
            error.push( this.name + " contains invalid email!");
            proceed = false;          
        }

        //check invalid file types and maximum size of a file
        if(this.type == "file"){
            if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
                if(this.value !== ""){
                    if(allowed_file_types.indexOf(this.value.type) === -1){
                        error.push( "<b>"+ this.value.type + "</b> is unsupported file type!");
                        proceed = false;
                    }

                    //allowed file size. (1 MB = 1048576)
                    if(this.value.size > max_file_size){ 
                        error.push( "<b>"+ bytes_to_size(this.value.size) + "</b> is too big! Allowed size is " + bytes_to_size(max_file_size));
                        proceed = false;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                error.push( "Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
                proceed = false;
            }
        }

    }); 

    $(error).each(function(i){ //output any error to element
        $('#' + message_output_el).html('<div class="error">'+error[i]+"</div>");
    }); 

    if(!proceed){
        return false;
    }

    $('#' + loadin_image_el).show();
}

//Callback function after success
function after_success(data){
    $('#' + message_output_el).html(data);
    $('#' + loadin_image_el).hide();
}

//Callback function to format bites bit.ly/19yoIPO
function bytes_to_size(bytes){
   var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
   if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
   var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
   return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}
</script>
```

here is the Html code

```
<form action="/ajax/createPostArticle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form">
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="cretor">
<textarea rows="4" id="contentMessage" class="form-control"></textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success">POST</button>
```

I want to send textarea input to php in request how can i achieve that

Comment: I don't see any `php` extension at your action link in the form or you are using custom url's???

Comment: yes I'm using custom url

Comment: what you got in ur action="/ajax/createPostArticle" file

Comment: @Plum action="/ajax/createPostArticle" == action="/ajax/createPostArticle.php" i just removed the php extension and action is woking fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send post data in ajax like this way :

```
var options = { 
    //dataType:  'json', //expected content type
    data: {id1: $('#id1').val()}, //Note the data here for sending values
    target: '#' + message_output_el,   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit: before_submit,  // pre-submit callback 
    success: after_success,  // post-submit callback 
    resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
};
```

Comment: it is sending blank textarea data

Comment: @SagarSingh : Try to check the post requests through Firefox FireBug utility.! If it is really posting no data..!

Comment: @SagarSingh : Remove the `dataType: `json`,` and I hope that it will start posting data..! Cuz right now it may be posting the data but it will be in JSON Format..!

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea rows="4" id="contentMessage" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

you are missing name attribute, it should be

```
<textarea rows="4" id="contentMessage" name="contentMessage" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

PHP understand post value by name.

Comment: after adding name="contentMessage" the jquery is sending contentMessage paremeter but when i echo it on the php page it shows nopthing echo $_POST['contentMessage'];

Comment: clear all the code in the ajax php page and echo $_POST['contentMessage']; and please add a type: 'POST' in the jquery options var options = {  type:'POST',
    //dataType:  'json', //expected content type

    data: {id1: $('#id1').val()}, //Note the data here for sending values
    target: '#' + message_output_el,   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
    beforeSubmit: before_submit,  // pre-submit callback 
    success: after_success,  // post-submit callback 
    resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
};